# Get URL in javascript without file extension

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In Google Analytics I'm tracking goals with virtual page views. I take

```
trackingURL = window.location.pathname+'thankyou.php';
```

and then

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview',trackingURL]);
```

The issue is when a page is something like www.domain.com/page.php it ends up being domain.com/page.phpthankyou.php and not tracking properly, but if it was domain.com/page/ and then it became domain.com/page/thankyou.php it would track properly.

How can I get the full url, without the extension, so I can add on /thankyou.php, but if it is already a directory with the / at the end, then I just want to add thankyou.php to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this **(which only replaces the extension with a slash if it finds it)**:

```
trackingURL = window.location.pathname.replace(".php","/") +'thankyou.php';
```

Which replaces `domain.com/page.php` with `domain.com/page/`